# Firebase getDownloadUrl does not work at first i neen to reload the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

When I try to display my image with the image url i got an error 404 not found and then when i reload the page the image appear. I know it's because of the image dont have time to get upload first but i don't know how to resolve this problem. If you have any idea, this is the code :

I first create a user and create a ref for my image then put my ref in my database then i get my data on my profile page and do a getDownloadUrl method to get my image url with my ref but like i said before i need to reload the page first to don't get the error.

```
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
                .then(registeredUser => {
                    const storageRef = app.storage().ref();
                    const fileRef = storageRef.child(registeredUser.user.uid + "/profile.jpg");
                    fileRef.put(file);

                    app.firestore().collection('Users')
                        .add({
                            uid: registeredUser.user.uid,
                            firstName: firstName.value,
                            lastName: lastName.value,
                            email: email.value,
                            companyName: companyName.value,
                            companyDomain: companyDomain.value,
                            profileImage: registeredUser.user.uid + "/profile.jpg"
                        })
 
let imageRef = userData[0].profileImage
    const imageUrl = (async () => {
      let imagePath = await app.storage().ref().child(imageRef).getDownloadURL()
      setProfileImage(imagePath)
    })()

    return (
      <>
        <Nav />
        <div className="container">
          <h1>Profile</h1>
          <div className="profile_container">
            <div className="image_container">
              <img src={profileImage} alt="profileImage" />
            </div>
            <div className="info_profile_container">
              <h3><strong>First Name:</strong> {userData[0].firstName}</h3>
              <h3><strong>Last Name:</strong> {userData[0].lastName}</h3>
              <h3><strong>Email:</strong> {userData[0].email}</h3>
              <h3><strong>Company Name:</strong> {userData[0].companyName}</h3>
              <h3><strong>Company
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is incomplete, so I'm going to provide you with pseudo code.

Try use effect to get what you need. This will retrieve the image every time `userData` changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
      if (userData) imageUrl(); //check whether userData is valid before fetching
}, [userData]) //get the image every time userData props changes.

const imageUrl = async() => {
  let imagePath = await app.storage().ref().child(imageRef).getDownloadURL()
  setProfileImage(imagePath)
})
```

Comment: then put imageUrl Firestore call.

Comment: I can't because i need my `let imageRef = userData[0].profileImage` which is undefined at first so it doesn't work

Comment: You should create another useEffect using my code. In your original code, you should replace [userData] with []. You should not use setUserData in useEffect, and use useData as the dependency, it will cause a loop. You can have multiple useEffect in a functional component.

Comment: It still doesn't work in the first time the image doesnt have time to get stored in my firebase storage i still need to reload the page

Comment: fileRef.put(file).then(snapshot => { then u should put ur codes here }.

Comment: THANKS ! IT WORKS ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
const Profile = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState()
  const [profileImage, setProfileImage] = useState()
  const users = app.firestore().collection('Users')

  useEffect(() => {
    users
      .where("uid", "==", `${currentUser.uid}`)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data()
        }))
        setUserData(data)
        console.log(data)
      })
 
  }, [userData])



  if (!userData) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>
  } else {
    let imageRef = userData[0].profileImage
    const imageUrl = async () => {
      let imagePath = await app.storage().ref().child(imageRef).getDownloadURL()
      setProfileImage(imagePath)
    }

    return (
      <>
        <Nav />
        <div className="container">
          <h1>Profile</h1>
          <div className="profile_container">
            <div className="image_container">
              <img src={profileImage} alt="profileImage" />
            </div>
            <div className="info_profile_container">
              <h3><strong>First Name:</strong> {userData[0].firstName}</h3>
              <h3><strong>Last Name:</strong> {userData[0].lastName}</h3>
              <h3><strong>Email:</strong> {userData[0].email}</h3>
              <h3><strong>Company Name:</strong> {userData[0].companyName}</h3>
              <h3><strong>Company Domain:</strong> {userData[0].companyDomain}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button className="danger" onClick={() => app.auth().signOut()}>Sign out</button>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
};
```